# Is there a way to detrmine class type of view's model in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What I'd like to achieve is to determine what type of class a partial view takes as a model before rendering the view, so I could pass to it a right type of a model.

Is there a way of doing this ASP .NET MVC?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  to me.

Comment: At runtime, there is no way to determine what type of model a partial view should take, and if you pass the wrong type, an exception will be thrown.  However, if you have multiple models, you can bridge the gap by using an interface; model expectations can be an interface, and then multiple models inherit that interface.